# Civicrm and Opayo ( formerly sagepay )

Tags: payment-processor

I'm trying to integrate Opayo with CiviCRM, I found an old extension but it seems to be unsupported for my CiviCRM version, is there a current extension for CiviCRM and Opayo?

Answer (score 2):

Opayo is now supported via [Omnipay extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/omnipay-multiprocessor-extension)